# Where does the ESO beta installer download the files?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I finished downloading the beta and ran out of space while *installing* the game. Then the installer decided to start downloading everything again; and so I decided to uninstall everything and play something else.

However, I'm still missing several GB of storage that I had free prior to beginning with this.

Which folder can I check to completely remove all files downloaded by the installer?
I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: Isn't the game still under NDA?

Comment: Thanks @kalina! Found it by searching my hardrive for "Zenimax"

Comment: I admit I'm no expert on NDAs @LessPop_MoreFizz, but does it cover this information? I didn't even install the game, I just want to remove all files left by its installer

Comment: Well if we're deeming this as not breaching the NDA I suppose I had best commit to an answer!

Comment: I don't think it's our job as a community to police NDA violations on behalf of other companies. (If jmfsg wants to get himself kicked out of the beta by asking how to completely uninstall it, that's his problem) On the other hand, one could argue that this question is off topic because the game is in beta, but I don't think a question about the game's launcher is really worth closing over this.

Comment: @Brant I don't think we're in the business of policing NDA's, but I do think that in the absence of anything better, [they provide a pretty reasonable heuristic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7486/3129) for where to draw the line regarding 'unreleased' content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Launcher for Elder Scrolls Online lives in its own folder. By default this folder will be:

```
C:\Program Files\Zenimax Online\Launcher
```

or (if using 64 bit Windows)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zenimax Online\Launcher
```

Since you're able to customise the installation location of the launcher, this path may be different for you - if this is the case, you can find where the launcher is installed on your machine by searching your computer for `Bethesda.net_Launcher.exe`.

All of the downloaded launcher data will be stored here if you wish to remove it, along with the uninstaller for the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes look for \zenimax Online\ on your computer.

that is where the remaining folders/files are.  I gained almost 30gb back after manually 
deleting this folder, the uninstall does not remove it.