# Is there a way to download ESO files from another PC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

As The Elder Scrolls Online went free-to-play, I wanted to reactivate my account and see what has changed.

Unfortunatelly, I deleted ESO from my PC and by now I've got a very slow internet connection. Downloading 32 GB of files would take a very long time. I calculated it painstakingly and my result is: forever.

Therefor I'm looking for other solutions. I've bought just a key online, so a hard copy isn't existent. Maybe Zenimax provides some solutions where I can download the setup files seperately to get it on a USB stick?

**Is there a way to download the needed files for playing for ESO on another PC?**

*(For clarification: I just need a way to copy files to my PC so that the game works as intended.)*

Comment: Just copy the installation over. done.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155283/where-does-the-eso-beta-installer-download-the-files?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience with ESO, and in fact, other MMO games all together, they do not alter files on your computer to play. Or rather, if you download it onto a drive at your mates, and chuck it on your PC at home, it will work. Just like that.

Comment: That's what I've been thinking. Just looking for a "better" solution, but I guess this one will give me the most recent files. Thanks! Just waiting a couple of hours to give other answers a try.

Comment: Might be worth re-buying the game on disc? I know you said you had bought a key.. but I work at an electronics retailer in Australia ( games tend to come with a bit of a mark up), and we've had it on for ten bucks.

Comment: Well if a Timelord has given me this tipp... going to look at retailers for that, but I guess downloading on a friends PC wouldn't take more than two days, so it's questionable if it's profitable. :)

Comment: No check, no downloading, no anything. It just has worked!

Comment: and that there, friend, is how we play video games at tafe and school :D

Answer (score 2):

You basically won't save any bandwidth by downloading the client off another source. If there's no game installation so far, the game client will download just the most recent version of the game.

The whole launcher as well as the game client itself both are very portable. They do not rely on any registry settings. Only constraint is the fact that the directory structure must stay intact and there shouldn't be any other files in those folders (or next to them). (Only registry entries written are for the uninstallation process as well as the default client language.)

Steps you can do:

- Install the game to a location where you'd like it to stay. Make sure you install the client to a new or empty folder. **Do not install the client to a generic path like `C:\Games` as this might cause the client to delete other non-game related files!** Instead install to `C:\Games\Zenimax Online` or any similar location with no other files/folders.
- Cancel the launcher downloading the game client and close it.
- Move the whole folder (in this example `C:\Games\Zenimax Online`) to your portable drive.
- Connect the drive to your other PC and run it right off that drive.
- Once finished downloading and patching, close the game client and remove the portable drive.
- Back at home move the whole folder back into position.

The same process may be used later on for patching, since some patches might be quite big.

In case you know someone who's got the game installed and patched, you can of course simply copy the whole folder structure without first bringing your own files with you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I may have mislead my question. It's not that I want it to have as a portable game. I just want to know whats the best way to download the game at a friend's PC and then later transfer it to my own PC so that I don't have to use my glacial internet connection.

Comment: @Trollwut just follow the steps. The game is indeed portable (conduit files stay on local PC though).